# Python to C algorithm

Tags: java, python, c

I am trying to find simple recursive implementation of change-making algorithm and all i could find is this (working) algorithm in python:

```
def min_change(V, C):
    def min_coins(i, aC):
        if aC == 0:
            return 0
        elif i == -1 or aC < 0:
            return float('inf')
        else:
            return min(min_coins(i-1, aC), 1 + min_coins(i, aC-V[i]))
    return min_coins(len(V)-1, C)
```

I dont understand python so i am asking for help if anyone could rewrite this small code in C or Java so it would be understandable to me. Or if anyone know of any implementation of this in C or Java can you post link please ?

Thank you for any help

edit:
I was able to do this:

```
int min_change(int * V, int C) {
    return min_coins(/*Length-last index*/, C)
}

int min_coins(int i, int C) {
    if (C == 0)return 0;
    else if (i == -1 || C < 0)return sizeof (int)*32;
    else return min(min_coins(i - 1, C), 1 + min_coins(i, C - V[i]));
}
```

Comment: It's probably easier to learn enough python to read this than it would be to re-write it. What's confusing? `def` defines a function. It's a little odd here that they're defining a function within another function, but that just scopes it. The rest of the syntax is very C-like, without the brackets of course. In python, the indentation defines what brackets would in C.

Comment: To expand @Collin's comment about defining the function in another function - that's a closure. Doing it that way allows `min_coins` to access the `V` variable from its parent namespace. I expect you could replace that with a third parameter to `min_coins` instead.

Comment: here's another [recursive algorithm plus very simple (to implement) iterative one in Python](https://gist.github.com/zed/35366bbe7eae1e14e99f). Could you describe  what you do not understand about the function definition that you've provided given that you already know C? Just add `int* V` argument to `min_coins()` and pass `V`'s length to `min_change()`. You could use `unsigned` type as a return value (number of ways is >=0), use `UINT_MAX` instead of `float('inf')` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the correct equivalent:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>

    int min_change0(int *V, int i, int aC)
    {
      if (aC == 0) {
        return 0;
      } else if (i == -1 || aC < 0) {
        return INT32_MAX - 1;
      } else {
        int a = min_change0(V, i-1, aC);
        int b = 1 + min_change0(V, i, aC - V[i]);
        return a <= b ? a : b;
      }
    }

    int min_change(int *V, int C)
    {
      int len = 0;
      while (V[len]) len++;
      /* min_coins(len(V)-1, C) */
      return len ? min_change0(V, len-1, C) : -1;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
      int total = 123;
      int values[] = {1,5,10,25,50,0 /* sentinel */};
      printf("minimal number of coins to change %i with 1, 5, 10, 25 and 50 coins is %i\n",
             total,
             min_change(values, total)
             );
      return 0;
    }
```

as 2*50 + 2*10 + 3*1 is 123

Comment: Is there any way i could remember coins i used ? So output would be 50,50,10,10,1,1,1 instead of just 7?

Comment: that is a very good question that I was unable to answer, though I like math and specially number theory, I'll have to defer such investigation, maybe asking in http://math.stackexchange.com/ should yield a prompt answer